# What are the third party solutions available for setting up enterprise search for an organization and important advantages of them?

Tags: search, full-text-search

We are currently working on setting up enterprise level search and need to evaluate the performance of different solutions available in the market. We need insights from experienced people in this field.

Thank you for helping.

P.S- I am new to this platform so may have made some mistake

Comment: Your new to this platform, so I would suggest to search in the website for answered questions and then ask a new, more specific question here.

Comment: After doing what @PaoloMelchiorre mentioned, have a look on Elasticsearch, Solr, Lucene.

Comment: But before studying an external services for your full-text it's better if you test the full-text capabilities of your databases. In some cases (e.g. PostgreSQL ) full-text search in your database is simpler and faster than an external service.

Answer (score 0):

Micro Focus [IDOL](https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/information-data-analytics-idol/overview) (Intelligent Data Operating Layer) provides an excellent platform search and knowledge discovery across the enterprise. We have a wide variety of connectors for the various content repositories in a typical enterprise. IDOL can detect and extract information from over 1000 file types.

Audio, Video and Images are also sources of information and IDOL can perform speech to text, OCR, image classification and a host of visual / audio analytics on unstructured content.

IDOL does all of this while respecting the security model of the content repository. It can map the security so the secure search results are returned in sub second responses. IDOL can map security of a user across the various content repositories. So if a user goes by usernameA in repo1 and user name A in repo2, its possible to map it easily in IDOL.

The strength of IDOL is the Adaptive Probablistic Concept Modelling capability which improves over a large volume of documents. So for example if you wanted to know what are the core concepts discussed in documents in a particular SharePoint site or File Share we can easily do this without firing a single keyword query to IDOL.

Recent advances in Natual Language Question and Answering has enabled the IDOL platform to literally ask a question to your document corpus. So a typical question would be, "Where does the code of conduct say about expense reimbursements on international trips?" and rather than going through each link. We can extract the passage most relevant to the question from 100s of documents and present the answer to the user.